# How to find feature in OpenLayers exsisting layer

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I have a vector layer in my OpenLayers applicaiton.

```
  var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
          url: "my geojson url"
      })
  })
```

my GeoJSON data fills the vector layer.

I have an AJAX query that gets single feature from server. But I need to check my layer to control if feature is in `layer`.

```
$.ajax(settings.url).then(function(response){
     how to check if response feature in my layer?
})
```

Response is GeoJSON formatted data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like:

```
  features = vectorSource.getFeatures();

  found = false;
  for (i = 0; i < features.length && !found; i++) {
    if (features[i].getId() === id) {
      found = true;
      //Here I'm removing it, but you could do anything you like
      features.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that by using the `hasFeature()` method of ol.source.Vector

```
var mySource = new ol.source.Vector({url: "geoJsonUrl"});
var myLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({source: mySource});

$.ajax(settings.url).then(function(response){
    var feature = the response feature
    //note the feature must be of type ol.Feature and i think it sholud have an id too
    if(mySource.hasFeature(feature)){
        //do logic here
     }
})
```

check the doc at [OpenLayers VectorSource hasFeature method](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#hasFeature)